# Python SDK Docker Client Failed to build Image

Tags: python, docker

i'm working on an virtualbox VM, and i use to build an docker image with a python script using a docker sdk client. here is the code:

```
try:
    #print(os.environ)
    client = docker.from_env()

    # building the base image
    image=client.images.build(path=os.getcwd(), dockerfile=os.getcwd()+"/Dockerfile", tag="xlrelease/builder", nocache=True, forcerm=True, use_config_proxy=True)

except Exception as er:
    print(er)
```

And i have the following exception:

```
  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

After investigate, i discover that it's when i add the ## use_config_proxy=True ## parameter, the  error appear.

Could someone help me fix this isssue ?

the Traceback was:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 41, in <module>
    image=client.images.build(path=os.getcwd(), dockerfile=os.getcwd()+"/Dockerfile", tag="xlrelease/builder", nocache=True, forcerm=True, use_config_proxy=True)
  File "/usr/local/python3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/models/images.py", line 279, in build
    resp = self.client.api.build(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 179, in build
    buildargs.setdefault(k, v)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

Comment: You should include the full traceback. The issue is that somewhere, something has a value of `None` and something else is trying to call a `setdefault` method on it.

Comment: ...the full traceback *and the code that is producing the traceback*.

Comment: ok, after finding the traceback, i found the full error and solves it by adding one parameter :  `image=client.images.build(path=os.getcwd(), buildargs={'tags':'test'}, dockerfile=os.getcwd()+"/Dockerfile", tag="xlrelease/builder", nocache=True, forcerm=True, use_config_proxy=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the issue by finding the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 41, in <module>
    image=client.images.build(path=os.getcwd(), dockerfile=os.getcwd()+"/Dockerfile", tag="xlrelease/builder", nocache=True, forcerm=True, use_config_proxy=True)
  File "/usr/local/python3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/models/images.py", line 279, in build
    resp = self.client.api.build(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/python3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 179, in build
    buildargs.setdefault(k, v)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

I have a new parameter(buildargs) when i call the client function:

```
    image=client.images.build(path=os.getcwd(), buildargs={'tags':'test'}, dockerfile=os.getcwd()+"/Dockerfile", tag="xlrelease/builder", nocache=True, forcerm=True, use_config_proxy=True)
```

This solved the issue